# How would one rewrite a program to eliminate side effects?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to research this problem in a java textbook.
The problem is to rewrite this program to eliminate the side effects,
where a change to the state of an object or program variable is produced by a call on a function (or a method, which is kinda the same thing).

package sideeffect;

```
public class SideEffect {

    **public static int x;**

    public static int f(int n){
        x = x * 2;
        return x + n;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        x = 5;

        //int result = f(x) + f(x);
        int result = 2 * f(x);
        //System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

The commented out lines are what happens when I implement the integer variable and it's printout.
If I implement those lines and comment out the other lines,
the result is 45.
If implement the other one,
the result is 30.
Is there a way to straighten out the program so there are no side effects?
I was thinking I remove the global variable line since it says in the book that it can lead to this bad,
confusing code.
But what else can I try?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The problem doesn't state a specific output. It only suggests to make the function accept the value of x to use as a parameter rather than modifying a global variable.

Comment: By "eliminate side effects", I guess you mean *externally-visible* side effects *produced by method execution*.  There are other kinds of side effect, too, which you cannot easily avoid in Java.

Comment: Getting rid of the global variable is on the right track. It's hard to fix a program if you don't know what its output should be though, so it's hard to say what the implementation of the `f` function should be.

Comment: The entire purpose of a program is to produce a side effect. If your program doesn’t have a side effect, like the print statement, you can replace it by an entirely empty program.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an assignment but stuff like this is always somewhat maddening.  The "problem" is that they are using a global variable in a way it should NEVER be used.  "Doctor it hurts when I do this. Don't do that".

In general static (class level) variables are seldom what you really want.  Also main() is for instantiating your objects and turning them lose on the world, not doing the heavy lifting like this was a C program.

Create classes and pass by value.  Don't use global variables unless you REALLY mean to have one and only one instance.

That's really about the best I can offer because it isn't clear from your question what "the correct" outcome is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, much more better:

package sideeffect;

```
public class SideEffect {

      public static int f(int x, int n){
        x = x * 2;
        return x + n;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int x = 5;
       int result = f(x , 5) + f(x, 5);
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

I've brung in x as a int in the public static int so I won't have to initialize the variable.

Answer (score -1):

This might work, but I'm not sure. I've commented the global variable, then declared int x in both the f method and main methods. The result is that it doesn't matter whether I use either "int result" calls, it's still going to be 10 as the output. But I could be wrong through:

```
public class SideEffect {

    **//public static int x;**

    public static int f(int n){
        int x = 0;
        x = x * 2;
        return x + n;
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 5;

        //int result = f(x) + f(x);
        int result = 2 * f(x);
        System.out.println(result);
        //System.out.println(result2);
    }

}
```

Comment: You can rewrite as: `public static int f(int n){ return n;}` Probably not what you want.